# I need a bidimensional data structure that contains sorted items

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Please I have the following situation.

I need to store a "list" of "lists" of a certain items,

where each list is sorted in descending order on the value of a field the item.

What kind of Java object can I use for this purpose?

Comment: `List<SortedSet<Data>>`?

Comment: Comparable and Collection.sort shall help

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Set can't have dupes.

Comment: @Nishant OP never said anything about having dups.

Comment: :) I believe in avoiding accidents.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's why it is safer to assume that she would have some :-)

Comment: Then `List<PriorityQueue<Data>>` would do it automatically for you, in case you don't want to call `Collections#sort` every time you add a new element.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think that's a perfectly upvoteable answer to OP's question :-)

Comment: Queue OTOH does not have a `get(index)` like List does, AFAIK. What I am saying that these are good alternatives, they may not necessarily replace List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want to call `Collections#sort` every time you add a new element, you can use `List<PriorityQueue<Data>>`, the [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) will sort the elements by you.

If your data doesn't admit duplicates, then you may use `List<SortedSet<Data>>`.

In the worst case, use `List<List<Data>>` and sort the elements every time you add a new element using `Collections#sort`.

Do the necessary tests according to your requirements before taking a decision.

Comment: Beware: iterating through a priority queue won't iterate in order.